# approximate count of rows in postgresql django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, database-table

I have a postgresql database connected to with django. In database there is lots of big tables which I want their row count. Because of large size of tables this takes a lot of time to execute.

I founded that the approximate count could be retrieved from `pg_class`. Is there any way to this in Django and not executing raw query?

Comment: You can do this with a `FuzzyCountManager`: https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-postgres-fuzzycount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to use a dedicated package for this named [`django-postgres-fuzzycount` [GitHub]](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-postgres-fuzzycount). This package provides a manager that will do the fast counting.

You can install the package with `pip` (for example in your local environment):

```
$ pip install django-postgres-fuzzycount
```

Then you can add the `FuzzyCountManager` to the models where you want to obtain an approximative count:

```
from django.db import models
from fuzzycount import FuzzyCountManager

class SomeModel(models.Model):

    #  ... (some fields) ...

    objects = models.Manager()
    approx = FuzzyCountManager()
```

and then you can count approximatively with:

```
SomeModel.approx.count()
```

In case you `.filter(..)`, Django will calculate the *real* number, since the `pg_class` table only stores an apprixmative number of rows for the *entire* table, so:

```
SomeModel.approx.filter(foo=bar).count()
```

will take more time (depending on indexes, etc.).

You can also "patch" the `objects` manager directly, but then obtaining the *real* number of records might be harder:

```
from django.db import models
from fuzzycount import FuzzyCountManager

class SomeModel(models.Model):

    #  ... (some fields) ...

    objects = FuzzyCountManager()
```

It is also nice that if you change the backend database to another database, the `FuzzyCountManager(..)` will act as a *normal* `Manager`, so in case you later change the database system, you do not have to rewrite the managers.

Comment: I don't want to "patch" the objects directly, because already have a custom manager, Added  `approx = FuzzyCountManager()` but got the error: `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'approx'`

Comment: @Miguel: you are likely working with `SomeModel.objects.approx`, but then it is a `QuerySet`, so that will not work. Note that `.objects` is only defined on the *model*, not on a manager or `QuerySet` that arises from that model.

Comment: @Miguel: you can however simply make a manager in the model `approx = FuzzyCountManager()`, and another `ojbects = models.Manager()`, then you thus can work with `SomeModel.approx` to count the number of elements approximately.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what about count the queryset? That is what I need.

Comment: @Miguel: you can count exactly with `SomeModel.objects.count()` or approximately with `SomeModel.approx.count()` if you implement it as in the first way (second code fragment).

Comment: Ok but I don't want to count the number of documents in the full collection, but only the documents I obtained from the query.

Comment: @Miguel: but you can not count approximately a filtered set. The idea is that for an approximate set, PostgreSQLwill store the total size of the table (in another table), and update it regularly, but that of course does not work with an arbitrary filter.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that out. A bit off-topic then, but any advice on what alternatives do I have to count an arbitrary filter? Because using `count` is really slow.

Comment: @Miguel: usually that is slow if you filter on fields that have no index. In that case the database has to perform a linear search. Usually by adding indexes that can be optimized.

Comment: Already added. Even with that is quite slow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66457799/how-to-improve-count-of-text-query-for-django-with-postgres