# How to improve count of text query for Django with Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm having a problem when counting query results for a full-text search. I have a model where one of the fields is:

`search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True`)

with the index:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = (GinIndex(fields=["search_vector"]),)
```

Then in the view I have the following query:

```
query = SearchQuery(termo,config='portuguese')
search_rank = SearchRank(F('search_vector'), query)
entries = Article.objects.annotate(rank=search_rank).filter(search_vector=query).order_by('-rank')
```

And now if I apply the count method to `entries` it takes a long time. About 2 seconds, when I have a small database with about 200k rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the `SearchRank` and just filter using the query it will use the GIN index and perform much, much faster:

```py
query = SearchQuery(termo,config='portuguese')
entries = Article.objects.filter(search_vector=query)
```

You can add [`.explain()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#explain) to end to take a look at the query and see if the index is used:

```py
print(entries.explain(analyze=True))
```

You should see the query using Bitmap Heap Scan and the Execution Time should be much faster.

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on your_table
...
Planning Time: 0.176 ms Execution Time: 0.453 ms
```

When you annotate like you are above, you are annotating ***every*** `Article` object - so postgres decides to perform a Seq Scan (or Parallel Seq Scan) which it decides is more efficient. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203755/why-does-postgresql-perform-sequential-scan-on-indexed-column)

Try adding `.explain(verbose=True)` or `.explain(analyze=True)` to your initial SearchRank method to compare.

```py
query = SearchQuery(termo,config='portuguese')
search_rank = SearchRank(F('search_vector'), query)
entries = Article.objects.annotate(rank=search_rank).filter(search_vector=query).order_by('-rank')

print(entries.explain(analyze=True))
```

I'm facing this issue myself, with a table with 990k entries that takes ~10 seconds. If you can filter the query before the annotation using any other fields - it will push the query planner back toward using the Index.

> If the SELECT returns more than approximately 5-10% of all rows in the table, a sequential scan is much faster than an index scan.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203827/12137312)